# recover column details after PCA and Kmeans

Tags: python, k-means, pca

I did KMeans clustering after reducing numerical columns in my DataFrame from 5 to 2 using PCA and plotted scatterplot

```
pc=PCA(n_components = 2).fit_transform(scaled_df)
scaled_df_PCA= pd.DataFrame(pc, columns=['pca_col1','pca_col2'])


#Then I did the KMeans and its plotting

label_PCA=final_km.fit_predict(scaled_df_PCA)
scaled_df_PCA["label_PCA_df"]=label_PCA

a=scaled_df_PCA[scaled_df_PCA.label_PCA_df==0]
b=scaled_df_PCA[scaled_df_PCA.label_PCA_df==1]
c=scaled_df_PCA[scaled_df_PCA.label_PCA_df==2]

sns.scatterplot(a.pca_col1, a.pca_col2, color="green")
sns.scatterplot(b.pca_col1, b.pca_col2, color="red")
sns.scatterplot(c.pca_col1, c.pca_col2, color="yellow")
```

I get 3 clusters from above based upon 2 columns reduced using PCA. Now I wish to get the columns back for further analysis of those clusters but I am not able to.
And when i use pc.components_  I get error :

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_33/4073743739.py in 
----> 1 pc.components_

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'components_'

or when I do scaled_df_PCA.components_
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'components_'

So I wanted to know how to recover details of columns back which were reduced during PCA.

Comment: You need to call `components_` on the fitted PCA instance itself, not on the transformed data, it's not entirely clear from your code but perhaps `final_km.components_`?

Comment: As I used KMeans after PCA for clustering, final_km is instance of Kmeans and pc.components_ was giving error as mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line from your code [stores an NDArray](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.fit_transform) into `pc` rather than the PCA instance.

```py
pc=PCA(n_components = 2).fit_transform(scaled_df)
```

An easy fix is to create the PCA instance first and then call `fit_transform()`.

```py
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
df_transformed = pca.fit_transform(scaled_df)
```

Afterwards, you can still access attributes and methods of the PCA instance, `pca`.